# Categorise String data in Excel using nested If-Statements or alternatively a Look-up Table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to categorise my data based on the string values contained in a specific cell. I.e. If cell P6 contains the word "hospital" or "sanatorium", cell B2 should list its category as being "hospital", if P6 contains "airport", "terminal" or "aviation", B2 should list "airport".

First I tried my luck with an If-function, however, I am failing to nest them correctly.

```
=IF(SEARCH("stadium",$P6)>=1,"Sport")
```

This works as it is supposed to. it either print the correct category or gives 'VALUE! error.

However, when I try to extend the statements, it does no recognize the added search-terms.

```
=IF(SEARCH("stadium",$P6)>=1,"Sport",IF(SEARCH("sanatorium",$P6)>=1,"Hospital"))
```

This still finds the string "stadium", but does not recognize "sanatorium". If P6 contains the word "sanatorium", this still gives me #VALUE!.

It would be great if you could point me into the right direction or alternatively, how I could achieve this using alternative methods such as look-up tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because, SEARCH returns a number or an error.  If the word is not found it returns an error.

So If the cell does not contain `stadium` the error `#VALUE` is returned to the first SEARCH and you cannot try to equate it to a number and the whole formula short circuits and `#VALUE` is returned.

Use `ISNUMBER` to overcome.  `ISNUMBER` will return `FALSE` if the return is an error:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("stadium",$P6)),"Sport",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("sanatorium",$P6)),"Hospital"))
```

---

Now as you hypothesized It would e better and easier to create a table with the search criteria and expected output, then use a lookup type formula to return the correct output:

```
=INDEX(F:F,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($E$1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH("zzz",E:E)))/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH("zzz",E:E)),A1))),1))
```

This will iterate through the table and return the first output of the first match.

[image]

Comment: Did it work for you?  If so please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer it is something only you can do and it will remove this from the unanswered queue.

Comment: Thanks for answer. This helped a lot. However, I wasn't able to expand on your solution. 


please see the following screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/emuhu5l.png
It works for the first three lines but later on it sometimes works, while most of the time it doesn't. Even when using the same terms as is the beginning. 


Please note that with the hospital keyword, excel throws different errors, depending on the row.

Comment: Sorry my bad.  I forgot to make `E1` absolute `$E$1`  see edit.  @Turtur

Comment: Missed another one.  See new edit

Comment: While this seemed to solve the problem first, there must still be an error somewhere. When expanding the table even more, Excel throws an Div/0-Error:https://i.imgur.com/HSt5HfO.png
The same happen when I am trying to adapt the approach to my personal sheet with a larger dataset.

Comment: That is a data problem, it is supposed to through those errors, evaluate a cell that returns the correct data.  You will see the same errors with the correct row number also showing up,  the `6` in the AGGREGATE ignores these errors.  For some reason the `airport` in those two cells have something unprintable in them that is causing excel not to recognize them as matches.  The issue is the data not the formula.  Retype the cells.

Comment: Also check the data in Column E to ensure there is not a space before or after the data.

Comment: You are right, seem like the data contained unprintables. Thanks again for your help! However, is my understanding correct that in order to make this work for the table at hand, i'd have to recast the strings in order to make sure they contain no unprintables? E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882525/vba-how-to-remove-non-printable-characters-from-data

Comment: yes, otherwise you will need to include the uprintables in the lookup table, otherwise how is excel supposed to know they are matches.